# Data Move from @api variable to @track variable

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
@api item;
```

item has data its shows independently like if i write like this

```
{item}
```

but if i am using this item in template like this

```
<template for:each={item} for:item="item">
                        <lightning-button style="padding:6px 12px;margin:0 0 15px 0;display:inline-block;"
                            value={item.value}
                            key={item.value}
                            label={item.label}
                            data-value={item.value}
                            onclick={TechDataFn}
                            variant="neutral" >
                        </lightning-button>
                    </template>
```

then there is error like "Item is not defined"

Comment: Can you check by changing name like  <template for:each={item} for:item="listObj" ?

Comment: yeah i did that

Answer (score 0):

for loops are used to iterate over lists.

`<template for:each={item}` means you are iterating over a list named as `item`

`for:item="item">` and this mean each individual element in your list is also named as `item` which is very confusing IMHO. You can make it as something else for simplicity

```
<template for:each={item} for:item="ele">
                        <lightning-button style="padding:6px 12px;margin:0 0 15px 0;display:inline-block;"
                            value={ele.value}
                            key={ele.value}
                            label={ele.label}
                            data-value={ele.value}
                            onclick={TechDataFn}
                            variant="neutral" >
                </lightning-button>
</template>
```

Comment: already tried this

Comment: Would you mind more code snippet and JS?